# XNA - Allowing mouse visibility - Where does the command go?

Tags: xna, mouse

So... Yeah.
I can't see the cursor in my game.
I've read here you have to place "this.IsMouseVisible=true;" somewhere in the main Game class constructor/initializer. 
When I tried this, the "IsMouseVisible" wasn't recognized.

Any help?

Also: I've tried loading a texture for the cursor, follow the Mouse position and draw it, but with no success.

Comment: It should work in either the constructor or `Initialize`. Can you give us some source code? (Or maybe a screenshot?)

Comment: The problem has been solved, I must have mistyped something. It worked when I placed it in the Initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    this.IsMouseVisible = true;
}
```

Maybe Initialize should do it? What exactly do you mean by "Not Recognized"